# AHK Script Issues

Tags: performance, autohotkey

The script contains binds for everything, gameplay to roleplay. Yes, it is pretty pathetic that I'd be using it, but I'm a fairly new player, and would like to try it out.

```
#IfWinActive GTA:SA:MP

;NGRP binds - Tyler J. Reeves

!Q::
Sendinput t/fpslimit 20{enter}
Return

!E::
Sendinput t/fpslimit 60{enter}
Return

Numpadpgdn::
Sendinput t/find john{enter}
Return

Numpadpgup::
Sendinput t/s Loiter Squad is sprinkling your daughter's tits, get used to it{enter}t/jerkoff{enter}
Return

;NumpadUp::
Sendinput t/getpizza{enter}
Return

NumpadHome::
Sendinput t/getmats{Enter}
Return

Insert::
Sendinput t/pvlock{enter}
Return

Home::
Sendinput t/car lights{enter}
Return

Numpad5::
Sendinput t/headbutt{enter}
Return

Del::
Sendinput t/car engine{enter}
Return

End::
Sendinput t/sb{enter}
Return

NumpadIns::
Sendinput t/enter{enter}
Return

NumpadDel::
Sendinput t/exit{enter}
Return

Numpad0::
Sendinput t/enter{enter}
Return

NumpadDot::
Sendinput t/enter{enter}
Return

NumpadEnter::
Sendinput t/accept bodyguard{enter}
Return

Numpad1::
Sendinput t/guard  2000{left 5}
Return

NumpadEnd::
Sendinput t/guard  2000{left 5}
Return

F3::
Sendinput t/me tightens his grip of the gun in his hands, squeezing the trigger as multiple rounds fire from the 

barrel.{enter}
Return

F6::
Sleep 500
Sendinput /gesture 2{enter}
Return

F4::
Sendinput t/me removes the clip from the weapon, dropping it carelessly on the floor as he replaces it with a full 

clip.{enter}
Return

F1::
Sendinput t/me extends his right hand inside his jacket, gripping the handle of a Glock 17 secured in a small 

holster..{enter}
Sleep 750
Sendinput t/do ..in his jacket pocket, quickly pulling the gun out and flicking the safety off.{enter}
Sendinput t/idles 2{enter}
Return

F2::
Sendinput t/me raises his right hand upwards as he slides his Glock 17 inside his jacket, securing it in a 

small...{enter}
Sleep 750
Sendinput t/do ...holster concealed in his jacket pocket while flicking the safety on.{enter}
Sendinput t/idles 2{enter}
Return

F10::
Sendinput t/gesture 6{enter}
Return

F12::
Sendinput t/gesture 14{enter}
Return

F11::
Sendinput t/chat 2{enter}
Return

!C::
Sendinput t/s 1323 Market Blocc{enter}
Return

!Z::
Sendinput t/me slowly crouches down; gently setting his steel briefcase on the ground; releasing the latches and 

opening it.{enter}
Sendinput t/bomb{enter}
Sleep 2500
Sendinput t/do There is a disassembled Sniper Rifle inside the briefcase.{enter}
Sleep 3000
Sendinput t/me takes out the 3-part sniper rifle out; quickly assembling it in a slick manner.{enter}
Sendinput t/bomb{enter}
Sleep 4000
Sendinput t/do (1/2) - Assembling the stock to the main rifle.{enter}
Sendinput t/bomb{enter}
Sleep 4000
Sendinput t/do (2/2) - Attatching the scope to the main rifle.{enter}
Sendinput t/idles 6{enter}
Sleep 4000
Sendinput t/me reaches his left hand inside the briefcase; snatching a pre-loaded magazine that lays inside.;

{enter}
Sendinput t/bomb{enter}
Sleep 4000
Sendinput t/me grips the bolt handle with his right hand; gently pulling it back as he slides the magazine in..

{enter}
Sendinput t/do ...- with his left hand; thus pushing the bolt into place with his right hand.{enter}
Sendinput t/idles 6{enter}
Sleep 3000
Sendinput t/do The Sniper Rifle would be fully assembled in Tyler's hand, ready to use.{enter}
Return

!X::
Sendinput t/me crouches down, - slowly dissasembling the Sniper Rifle in his hand.{enter}
Sendinput t/idles 6{enter}
Sleep 2500
Sendinput t/do (1/3) - Dissasembling the stock from the main rifle.{enter}
Sendinput t/bomb{enter}
Sleep 4000
Sendinput t/do (2/3) - Detatching the scope from the main rifle.{enter}
Sendinput t/idles 6{enter}
Sleep 4000
Sendinput t/do (3/3) - Sliding the magazine out from the rifle.{enter}
Sleep 4000
Sendinput t/me quickly loads the 3-part Sniper Rifle inside the briefcase; shutting it close.{enter}
Sendinput t/bomb{enter}
Return

!B::
Sendinput t/cancelbind{enteR}
Return

!F::
SendInput t ................./´¯/)........{enter}
sleep 700
SendInput t ............../....//.........{enter}
sleep 1001
SendInput t ............../....//.........{enter}
sleep 1001
SendInput t ......../´¯/...../´¯\.........{enter}
sleep 1001
SendInput t ....././.../..../..../.I_.....{enter}
sleep 1001
SendInput t ...(.(....(....(..../.)..)....{enter}
sleep 1001
SendInput t ....\................\/.../...{enter}
sleep 1001
SendInput t .....\................. /.....{enter}
sleep 1000
SendInput t .......\..............(.......{enter}
sleep 1000
SendInput t .........\.............\......{enter}
Return

::/sitdown::/me places his right hand behind him as he slowly falls into a sitting position; adjusting himself-...

{enter}t/do ...- confortably on the ground.{enter} t/sunbathe 8{enter}
Return

::/standup::/me slowly pushes himself up from the ground utilizing his right hand; brushing the back of his 

pants-..{enter}t/do ...- with both hands.{enter}t/sunbathe 9{enter}
Return

::/trunkopen::/me gently slides his hand under the trunk handle, gripping it firmly as he pulls it out; raising the 

trunk-..{enter}t/do ...- open.{enter}t/bar 2{enter}t/car trunk{enter}
Return

::/trunkclose::/me slowly raises his left hand, placing his fingertips on the edge of the trunk as he slams it 

shut.{enter}t/salute{enter}t/car trunk{enter}
Return

::/roll3dice::/me quickly shakes the three dice in his hand; gently releasing them as they roll forward.{enter}

t/dice{enter}t/dice{enter}t/dice{enter}

::/roll2dice::/me quickly shakes the two dice in his hand; gently releasing them as they roll forward.{enter}

t/dice{enter}t/dice{enter}
Return

::/roll1dice::/me quickly shakes the single die in his hand; gently releasing it as it rolls forward.{enter}t/dice

{enter}
Return

::/exitcar::/me gently grabs the door handle before slowly pulling on it, thus swinging the door open-..{enter}t/do 

..- as he slides himself out of the seat, shutting the door behind him.{enter}
Return

::/entercar::/me slides his hand over the door handle; gripping it firmly as he pulls it outwards, thus swinging 

the door open-..{enter}t/do ..- as he slides himself into the seat, shutting the door behind him.{enter}

::/driveby::/me quickly rolls down the window as he maintains a firm grip on his submachine gun, aiming it out of 

the window-...{enter}t/do ...- with his right hand as he holds onto the roof of the vehicle with his left.{enter}

::/nodriveby::/me quickly positions himself back inside the vehicle; sliding a new magazine into his sub machine 

gun  before-...{enter}t/do ...- rolling the window back up.{enter}

::/smokecigar::/me raises the cigar to his mouth, holding it in between his lips as he inhales the smoke.{enter}

t/gesture 15{enter}t/do Tyler exhales the smoke as he brings the cigar back to his side.{enter}
Return

::/smokeweed::/me raises the blunt to his mouth, holding it in between his lips as he inhales the smoke.{enter}

t/gesture 15{enter}t/do Tyler exhales the smoke as he brings the blunt back to his side.{enter}
Return

::/tagwall::
{
Sendinput /me looks in both directions with a suspicious facial expression before shaking the spray can in his 

right hand.{enter}
Sleep 4000
Sendinput t/cheer 7{enter}
Sleep 12000
Sendinput t/me extends his right arm outwards, aiming the spray can at the wall as he gently pushes down on the 

nozzle..{enter}
Sleep 2500
Sendinput t/tag 2{enter}
Sleep 5500
Sendinput t/do ..with his index finger.{enter}
Sleep 20000
Sendinput t/do Blue paint emits from the tip of the spray can as Tyler tags the wall in an experienced manner.

{enter}
Sleep 15000
Sendinput t/me lowers the spray can to his side as he oberves the tag on the wall with a wide grin on his face.

{enter}
Sleep 2500
Sendinput t/tag 1{enter}
Sleep 17900
Sendinput t/do The tag reads: '1323 Market Blocc' with the sketch of a handgun below it.{enter}
Sleep 20000
Sendinput t/me crouches down, extending his right hand outwards once again as he signs the tag with the innitials 

'TJ'.{enter}
}
return


;!numpad5
Sendinput t/me grabs the backpack on his back, gently setting it on the ground as he begins to unzip it open. -- 

*ZIP{!}*{enter}
Sendinput t/bomb{enter}
Sleep 1000
Sendinput t/dt 8{enter}
Sleep 3000
Sendinput t/me reaches both hands inside the backpack, grabbing a SPAS-12, sliding it out from the opening of the 

bag.{enter}
Sleep 3000
Sendinput t/me cocks the chamber of the SPAS-12 back, loading the weapon with standard shotgun shell ammunition.

{enter}
Sendinput t/reload 1{enter}
Sleep 1000
Sendinput t/idles 6{enter}
Sleep 4000
Sendinput t/me quickly grabs the backpack from the ground with his left hand as he tightly holds the SPAS-12 in his 

right.{enter}
Sendinput t/wt 8{enter}
Sendinput t/bar 2{enter}
Return

;Autocorrect

::avengence::a vengeance
::adbandon::abandon
::abandonned::abandoned
…
::sionists::Zionists
::jut::just
::/rp::/pr
::/r p::/pr

Return
```

When you try the script in Auto Hot Key, it'll give you an error as if the line does not have a given action.

If anyone has a solution to this problem, and or able to make that script work, I will be very greatful and I might try to work in a reward, if I can. Thanks.

Comment: Please post (the relevant parts of) the code here, not on pastebin. Also you need to tell us *which* error message *you* are getting (on what line), nobody's going to try out your script.

Comment: Yes, just post the code that you have a problem with, and also say just what the problem is.  You shouldn't post your entire script here like you would in an ahk forum.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this code, you get an error message "error at line 80".
So this is where you should look.

Line 80 is

```
 barrel.{enter}
```

and that's just leftover from line 78.

If you get a text editor that displays line numbers this will be easy to fix.

You have 20-30 lines in the script that have these problems so you can fix them one by one.

The error messages will show you which line to fix.